# URL shortcut icon on multuple PCs

Tags: windows, shortcuts, icons

I created a shortcut for a webpage on my desktop.  I added a custom .ico image for the icon picture.  When I copy this shortcut over to another computer it doesn't keep that icon.  Is there any way I can make it so that custom image stays there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is not embedded in the shortcut, nor can it be.

The .ICO file has to exist where the shortcut can get to it, and it has to be where the shortcut is configured to look for it.

You'll need to provide the icon with the shortcut, and have the user put it the same path (on their system) the shortcut refers to.

This is why installers usually generate the shortcuts after the program is installed.  User installs the program to their desired path, and this includes the ICO file.  The installer now knows where the ICO file is, so it can create a shortcut that has that icon referenced properly.

Alternatively, you could perhaps use one of the system icons in the SHELL32.DLL system file, and reference it with `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`, as all versions of Windows should have that file, with those same icons in that same spot, and since it's using the `%systemroot%` variable, it doesn't matter where the user actually installed Windows, it will resolve properly.

Comment: Is there a workaround that would allow me to get the path changed on each computer without having to go around and do each one?

Comment: Depends, are you on a network that can control the files on all the clients? If so then yes, just use some scripting, and/or use a network location that's available to all client computers to store the ICO, and then reference that network location in the shortcut.

Comment: Yes, I am on a network that can control the files.  Do you know how you would do it with scripting?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question, one which depends on much more information then what's provided here. :)  Go try some stuff, and come back when/if you get stuck with a specific problem scripting them out, and ask new, specific questions about that problem.